# I'd like to make an http request every second, until a particular result is returned and then stop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried using callbacks first (happy to post this code if requested), but when I ran it nothing would happen. So I have now tried to have a go with promises (which I'm not very familiar with), but again had the same issue, nothing happens.

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

I feel like it's probably something to do with async, but I thought using a promise would fix that?

```
let btcmOrderStatus = undefined;
let orderGuid = 987654321;

//Promise Part One
function getOrderStatus()
{
    return new Promise(resolve => 
    {
        client.getOrderDetail([orderGuid], function(err, data)
        { 
            tempOrderStatus = data.orders[0].status;
            resolve(tempOrderStatus);
       });
   });
}

//Promise Part Two
async function primeFunction()
{
    var btcmOrderStatus;
    btcmOrderStatus = await getOrderStatus();
    console.log("Status : " + btcmOrderStatus);    
}

while (btcmOrderStatus != "Cancelled") {
    primeFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note that in your code you don't actually have any 1-second delay. You probably meant to have one in your `primeFunction`?

Here's one way to do it:

```js
function makeRequest() {
  // Pretend we're doing a request by waiting a random time up to 2 seconds,
  // and return true (for success) 30% of the time
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Response received");
      resolve(Math.random() < 0.3);
    }, Math.random() * 2e3);
  });
}

function wait1Second() {
  // Wait one second, then resolve the promise
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1e3);
  });
}

let count = 0;
function requestAndWait() {
  count++;
  const timer = wait1Second();
  makeRequest()
  .then((success) => {
    if (success) {
      console.log(count, "success; stop");
    } else {
      console.log(count, "not success");
      timer.then(requestAndWait);
    }
  });
}

requestAndWait();
```

In this code the `requestAndWait` method starts a 1-second timer, but then without waiting for it to finish sends the request. When the request returns we check whether it was a success. If so, we're done, and we ignore the timer. If it was not successful, we ensure the timer is finished (this may be immediately if the request took more than a second, or may take a little time if the request was fast) before calling `requestAndWait` again to start over.

If you instead just always wanted to wait one second between receiving one response and sending the next request, you just need to not start the timer until you receive the response.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I inserted that 'await' as per your suggestion, but I get an error: "Unexpected identifier" for the primeFunction after the await. 

And that's right, I did remove the 1 second delay. I thought perhaps that could be what was jamming up the works. 

Is there a better way to achieve my "keep making request until variable equals x" loop?

Comment: I've revised my answer. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm after. I'm going to tinker with it and try to get it to work in my code. Again, thanks so much.

Comment: Works like a charm. This has been really helpful, thanks.